# SSIS lookups - unknown code determination

Tags: ssis

Multiple SSIS packages import data into multiple reference tables (i.e. Country, Currency, Language, etc).

Each of these tables have special values in the case that incoming data codes are not part of the codes found in these reference tables (i.e. Language has an Unknown code). This is done to keep referential integrity and to track incoming codes that are unknown to our system. It is completely normal and we need to keep this process.

How can SSIS easily determine that the incoming value is not part of the referenced set of codes? When this happens, how to assign to it the Unknown codes?

Is there a way to do this globally over several columns?

I am trying to avoid using a Lookup task for each column in the source.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hello. I did not understand your question. can you give an example perhaps?

Comment: imported data has code 4, but code 4 doesnt exist in reference table Codes. How to detect this in SSIS and assign it a default value without using a lookup (because there are many fields to lookup)?

Answer (score 0):

the only possible way I see is a merge join operator (with full join) with the codes table and then use a derived table to transform the NULLs on whatever you want.

But why dont you want to use a lookup? just because the amount of columns you have to lookup and you are worried about performace? If thats the problem I suggest you to try to implement the lookups with the FULL CACHE option configured. This way, the lookup query (codes on your example) will be executed only once and result will be kept in memory.

Comment: What are the implications of using a SQL Task after the Data Flow Task to just update the values from a SQL update statement?

Comment: oh, if have that possibility that would be even better

Comment: I agree with Diego, the update statement would be set-based a likely perform better. The name for this type of operation - updating after loading - is ELT: Extract, Load, Transform (in case you want to read more about this pattern...).

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup transformation. Thats the easiest way of achieving this.